# c++ function templates with not arbitrary parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Consider this c++ code that works fine:

```
template <size_t N>
int check(std::array<unsigned char, N> buf){
    std::cout << N << "-" << buf.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::array<unsigned char, 20> a;
    std::array<unsigned char, 30> b;
    std::array<unsigned char, 40> c;

    check(a);
    check(b);
    check(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to explicitly instantiate "check" for N=20 and N=30, but disable any other implicit instantiation?

That means that I would like to get a compile time error if I use "check(c)",

Edit:

In fact I wanted to have the same implementation, so a template was the right choice, and I wanted to just have a compile time error if for some reason I instantiate it with a parameters that is not supposed to exist.
**Because of that the static_assert (c++11) solution looks the best, as complete for the problem and very human readable.**

Comment: You might want to read about [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert).

Comment: Just for completeness, you can also look into partial template specialization (static assert is the easiest one here though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `static_assert` to throw a compile time error if `N` is anything other than 20 or 30.

```
template <size_t N>
int check(std::array<unsigned char, N> buf) 
{
    static_assert(N == 20 || N == 30, "N must be 20 or 30.");

    std::cout << N << "-" << buf.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert):

```
template <size_t N>
    int check(std::array<unsigned char, N> buf){
    static_assert(N==20 || N==30, "invalid value of N");
    std::cout << N << "-" << buf.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It will cause a compile time error for invalid values of `N`. See it [live.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1ef1057841fdb34)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways of doing this.

One way would be:

```
template <size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<N == 20 || N == 30, int>::type
check(std::array<unsigned char, N> buf) {
  //..
}
```

A few thoughts about choosing between this and `static_assert` shown in the other answers:

- `static_assert` may be viewed by some as more clean, clear way of expressing your constraint than `enable_if`
- (the most important difference in my opinion): this way the constraint is part of the function interface, i.e. the definition of the function expresses the constraint. `static_assert` is part of the implementation. In more complex code this can even affect how the function overloads.
- with `static_assert` you get a clear message of what is wrong when the constraint isn’t satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this alternative to static_assert and the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

An other way is to *delete* the function:

```
template <size_t N>
void check(std::array<unsigned char, N> buf) = delete;

void check(std::array<unsigned char, 20> buf)
{
    std::cout << 20 << "-" << buf.size() << std::endl;
}

void check(std::array<unsigned char, 30> buf)
{
    std::cout << 30 << "-" << buf.size() << std::endl;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/m1YLn9)

Comment: But you are providing implementations independently of the template...?

Comment: Overloading is often better than specialisation for function.

Comment: Oh ok, so I would actually remove the template code, if I was not using it elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

If you are treating the arrays differently, a template is useless in your case.
Just provide some overloads:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int check(std::array<unsigned char, 20> buf){
    std::cout << "Handling an array of size 20\n";
    return 0;
}

int check(std::array<unsigned char, 30> buf){
    std::cout << "Handling an array of size 30\n";
    return 0;
}
int check(std::array<unsigned char, 40> buf){
    std::cout << "Handling an array of size 40\n";
    return 0;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::array<unsigned char, 20> a;
    std::array<unsigned char, 30> b;
    std::array<unsigned char, 40> c;

    check(a);
    check(b);
    check(c);

    // std::array<unsigned char, 0> d;
    //error: no matching function for call to ‘check(std::array<unsigned char, 0ul>&)'
    //check(d);

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, if the code is the same, a static_assert is good choice (see @Joachim Pileborg comment)