# Condition for const integer template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

Can I choice a template method by checking const integere parameter?

I need something like this

```
template <size_t N <= 90>
void f1(){....}

template <size_t N > 90>
void f2(){....}
```

My solution is

```
template <size_t N>
void f()
{
    N <= 90 ? f1(N) : f2(N);
}
```

But I think this approch is not very good becouse f() will always calls at run-time (probably not if compiler very clever).
What is the best way to do think like this?

Comment: Read about SFINAE. -- *Edit: Hm, on a second thought, that's overkill here. But still nice to know about.*

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209654/c-function-templates-with-not-arbitrary-parameters (can be adapted very easily)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Straightforward transformation with SFINAE and `std::enable_if`:

```
template <std::size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<N<90, void>::type
f(){....}

template <std::size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<N>=90, void>::type
f(){....}
```

Still, the straight-forward solution seems best in the example.

Comment: @dyp: No, it does not. Though it admittedly looks suspicious. The ellipses on the other hand...

Comment: Ah, right. `>=` is a single token. `>` would be problematic.

Answer (score 10):

You could try a simple tag dispatch implementation like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

void f(std::integral_constant<bool, true>) { /* ... */ }
void f(std::integral_constant<bool, false>) { /* ... */ }

template <std::size_t N>
void f()
{
    f(std::integral_constant<bool, N <= 90>{});
}
```

You can extend this scheme to more conditions by replacing the `bool` type with a larger integeral or enum type and adding more conditions.

Comment: +1 even if there is an unbalanced closing parenthesis on the penultimate line. ;-)

Comment: Why not `std::true_type`/`std::false_type`?

Comment: @0x499602D2: This way it's clearer how you'd generalize the approach.